# How to get pixel width and height of String?

Tags: delphi, text, canvas, delphi-7

How do you to use [GetTextExtentPoint32W](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Delphi 7 to get the pixel width and height of a wide string before it is output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  extent: TSize;
  S: WideString;
begin
  S := 'This is the integral sign: '#$222b;
  if not GetTextExtentPoint32W(Canvas.Handle, PWideChar(S), length(S), extent) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  TextOutW(Canvas.Handle, (Width - extent.cx) div 2, (Height - extent.cy) div 2,
    PWideChar(S), length(S));
end;
```

The `GetTextExtentPoint32W` will place the width and height in `extent.cx` and `extent.cy`, respectively.

The last line will then use `TextOutW` to draw the string centered both horizontally and vertically on the client area.